# A way to get the exact discord message content

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

If you type `:a:` or `:gun:`, it sends an emote in discord.
What I'm trying to do, is if someone sends just the string that is in between those `:` (that is, in this case, I showed, 'a' or 'gun'), my bot would analyze it and check if it can be 'translated' to an emote.

I tried to do:

```js
if (msg.content.length === 1)
```

But `msg.content` keeps on being `:(string):` so it doesn't work.

I am currently searching for other ways and will keep this updated. Any tips will be highly appreciated!

Edit: Went with [this api](https://emoji-api.com/#examples) as I found no other way

Comment: msg.content is :(string): for strings that are not emojis? Could you share a screenshot/code snippet so I can understand better?

Comment: like if you type :gun: it transforms into a single emote, and i assumed that msg.content would be 1, because its just that emote but instead it still shows :gun: so i cant use msg.content.length==1

Comment: ok why are you checking emotes? I thought you are trying to turn non-emote strings into emotes?

Comment: kinda: imagine if you send just 'gun', the bot would add the 2 :, then send the message, check the message and if it translates to a valid emote (if you send 'augaugaug' as it is no emote, it would do nothing) it would give you a role with that emote

Comment: the bot would check it's own message?

Comment: after all that refining done, yes

Comment: @JasaunLins Do you want to convert it like this? `:slight_smile:` -> ``

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple caveats with this: 1) There does not appear to be anyway of checking against standard emojis; only guild (i.e. custom) emojis. 2) It may be possible with a 3rd-party plugin.

Regarding #1, this will translate a message into a GUILD emoji:

```
const emoji = message.guild.emojis.cache.find(e => e.name === message.content);
    
if (emoji) {
    message.channel.send(`<:${emoji.name}:${emoji.id}>`);
}
```

Regarding #2, check out [emoji-regex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-regex). From what I can tell, convert the message to an emoji, and compare it to what `emoji-regex` tells you. If it matches, then you can send the emoji.

Comment: yea i already have this, both the regex and custom emojis, now i am just looking for a way to check if strings can be converted to emojis. Thanks tho!

Comment: Yeah, if you have the ID of the emoji, then use the format above. I *think* the `:string:` is a special function of Discord (similar to slash commands). I tried sending `:string:` and it just printed the text. I believe you have to use the `<:name:id:>` format.